# Magento 2 Bundle product with multiple inventory sources

Tags: magento, magento2

first off a happy new year to you all.

We're running into the following problem and are having arguments with our dev's on how to solve/tackle the issue.

We're expanding into a new country and have generated a new Website, Store and Storeview to do this in our existing Magento2 (v2.4.2) install. As we'll be operating under a different name/company specific to that country.
In Magento we've added a new Inventory Source, because we'll be holding stock in a warehouse in that country. Timewise it's not efficient to ship from our main warehouse.
So far this all works correct, test orders etc are all deducted from the local stock source.

Now comes the part that goes wrong:
Bundle products. Whenever we want to save a bundle product in the admin, we get the error

Product "123456" cannot be added to bundle product as bundle product has "Ship Bundle Items Together" and "123456" product assigned to multiple sources or has different source then rest of bundle items.

Product 123456 is assigned to both Inventory Sources, so are the other items in the bundle.
So it seems that the error thrown at us, is incorrect.

I don't want to change the "Ship bundle items together" option, as that would pull stock from multiple inventory sources.

Has anyone here had experience with this? Or knows a clever workaround past this?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2.3.0 + MSI support bundle products in Single Stock Mode (on Default Source and Default Stock). In this setup, Magento reuses the legacy CatalogInventory Stock Status index where Bundle products are supported. That's why merchants who use Bundle products on a single stock are not affected.

You can read more about Supported Product types here: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory-about-product-types.html

Currently, there is no possibility to assign Bundle Products to custom sources, as a new Inventory indexation mechanism (which builds indexes per each Stock) does not support indexation of Bundle Products yet. This functionality is part of the Milestone 3 MSI backlog which you mentioned above.